# In Django admin, include auth.User as an inline

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I've seen lots of questions the other way around, which have something along the following:

```
class UserProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = UserProfile
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name_plural = 'profile'

class NewUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = (UserProfileInline, )

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, NewUserAdmin)
```

What I want to do is the reverse, but I can't seen to get it working.  Here's the code I have that isn't working.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from myapp.models import SpecialUserType

class UserInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = User
    can_delete = False

class IncludeUserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (UserInline,)

admin.register(SpecialUserType, IncludeUserAdmin)
```

How can I make this work so that `User` is an inline in the admin of `SpecialUserType`?

The error that I'm getting is:

```
<class 'django.contrib.auth.models.User'> has no ForeignKey to <class 'students.models.SpecialUserType'>
```

This makes sense, because the `OneToOneField` is housed in the `SpecialUserType` model, obviously and not in `User`.  But how can I get it to reverse on the `OneToOneField`?

(I know this might seem an unusual thing to do, but there is a good reason that I want to set up the admin this way and not the other way around.)

Comment: What version of Django are you using?

Comment: Wouldn't it work for you to subclass the User model in order to add it the missing relation ?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it can't be done. I've ran into the problem before myself a few times.

As the error message says, the inline model must have a ForeignKey (or OneToOneField) pointing to the main model.

As others have mentioned, I have found subclassing User very helpful for me:

```
class UserProfile(User):
    user = OneToOneField(User, parent_link=True)
    # more fields, etc
```

Comment: When this question was originally asked, subclassing `User` wasn't an option.  Fortunately, now it is.

Comment: believe it or not, but I've been subclassing User since March 2010, just without AUTH_USER_MODEL.